# Is there a library or technique to support query parameters in getStaticProps in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, query-string

I'm using Next.js for my application and I have a page where I need to fetch data at build time using the `getStaticProps` function. I want to be able to handle query parameters in this function, but by default, it doesn't provide direct support for query parameters.

Is there a recommended library or technique that I can use to handle query parameters within the `getStaticProps` function in Next.js?

I've come across the query-string library, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach or if there are any other alternatives available. I would appreciate any suggestions or examples that can help me achieve this functionality.

Comment: You no need any library just use {cache: "force-cache"} in fetch API so you can cache your results. [Refernce](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch)

Comment: what if i need dynamic data on every request

Answer (score 0):

`query parameters` is usually used for filtering, sorting, or pagination. those are dynamic, changes by user choice and your results also changes by the stored data in database. Based on your need, you have to use `getServerSideProps` which runs for every request in `pages` directory pages.

`getStaticProps` runs only at build time. (in dev mode, it runs in every request). At build time, next.js will generate static html's and serve those html files.

Answer (score -2):

In Next.js, handling query parameters in the `getStaticProps` function can be achieved using the built-in `query` object available in the `context` parameter. However, if you prefer using a library to handle query parameters, `query-string` is indeed a popular choice.

The `query-string` library provides utility functions for parsing and stringifying query parameters. It can be used effectively in the `getStaticProps` function to handle query parameters. Here's an example of how you can use `query-string` in Next.js:

1. Install the `query-string` library using npm or yarn:

```
npm install query-string
```

or

```
yarn add query-string
```

2. Import the library in your Next.js page file:

```js
import queryString from 'query-string';
```

3. Use `queryString.parse()` to parse the query parameters in the `getStaticProps` function:

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  // Get the query parameters from the context
  const { query } = context;

  // Parse the query parameters using queryString.parse()
  const parsedQuery = queryString.parse(query);

  // Access the individual query parameters
  const { param1, param2 } = parsedQuery;

  // Fetch data based on the query parameters
  // ...

  return {
    // Return the data as props
    props: {
      // ...
    },
  };
}
```

Using `query-string` allows you to easily parse and access the query parameters within the `getStaticProps` function.

Alternatively, if you prefer not to use a library, you can directly access the query parameters from the `context` object's `query` property. For example:

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { query } = context;

  // Access the individual query parameters
  const { param1, param2 } = query;

  // Fetch data based on the query parameters
  // ...

  return {
    // Return the data as props
    props: {
      // ...
    },
  };
}
```

Both approaches should work effectively in handling query parameters within the `getStaticProps` function in Next.js. Choose the one that suits your preferences and project requirements.

Comment: getStaticProps generates the page at build time. There's no way to getquery params using context parameter

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT